# Where we can get the help page of the sonarqube server versions along with build numbers?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Where we can get the help page of the sonarqube server versions along with build numbers?

Example:
SonarQube server version  6.7.1.34867

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version and build number of the SonarQube server is displayed on the last line of your SonarQube server page footer, example: Community Edition - Version 7.4 (build 18908)

[image]